# venv using the wrong interpreter in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

As the title explains, powershell uses the wrong python and pip executables in virtual environments.

I created the virtual environment using `python -m venv venv` and activated it with `./venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`

The activation scripts runs as expected and on the lefthand side of the shell can I see: `(venv) P: C:\path` indicating that the virtual environment is activated. However, when I write python or pip, powershell uses the system wide binaries instead of the ones in the virtual environment. Therefore when I try installing packages with `pip` they get installed system wide instead of in the venv.

I can use `./venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip` and install packages that way in the virtual environment. Though this workaround is rather tedious and wonders if anyone knows a way to fix the underlying issue?

EDIT 1: The path variable contains `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts` folder as the top entry. However, using the absolut path `C:\path\to\venv\Scripts\python.exe` does not work. Powershell says it can't find it. But the relative path as described above do work.

Comment: What does the Path environmental variable look like? Does is have the `./venv/Scripts` folder in there? Do you see anything extraordinary in the Path?

Comment: The path variable have the `./venv/Scripts` folder at the top, before the python installation folder. So it is strange that powershell ignores that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem!
I had accidentally renamed the venv folder after i created it, and therefore the path was pointing to the wrong location